# Как правильно рассчитать коэффициент полезного использования пространства на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, frontend

https://codepen.io/212ww134/pen/ZEPbOdV [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 const totalBlockArea = coloredBlocks.reduce((total, block) => total + block.width * block.height, 0);
            const totalContainerArea = container.width * container.height;
            const fullness = 1 - internalVoidArea / (internalVoidArea + totalBlockArea);
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnf_5h1PDZwVaoyPxUxfM85aGzVEmW2K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Как  определяется этот коэффициент?

Comment: 1−(площадь внутренних пустот)/(площадь внутренних пустот+площадь всех блоков)

Comment: Внутренняя пустота - странная штука. Блок 11 на картинке подвиньте немного вниз. Коэффициент станет равным единице? Больше нет внутренней пустоты, и нет проблемы. Другими словами, коэффициент легко сделать единичным сделав заполнение хуже. :)

Comment: Поместите в вопрос исходную задачу, которую вы решаете.

Comment: оно то так)) но там блоки заполняют пространство согласно алгортитмам

Comment: Можно решить за квадрат от числа прямоугольников заметанием горизонтальной прямой. Заметание построит граф незанятых областей. В графе надо будет отыскать компоненты связности. Для каждой компоненты нужно будет определить касается ли она края картинки. Квадрат можно ускорить до NlogN, но нужно будет сортированное дерево.

Comment: спасибо огромное))) буду пробовать

Comment: Это недели на две работы.

Comment: мне дали  5 дней, осталось 2)

Comment: Тогда так: все прямоугольники растеризуются в текстуру. На текстуре отыскиваются компоненты связности для не закрашенных областей. Для компонент не касающихся краёв, считается количество пикселей. Надо много   памяти, но будет работать.

Comment: спасибо), сейчас попробую